# How are Item Definitions managed

Tags: sitecore-commerce

How are Item Definitions managed in Sitecore Commerce 9.1?  They are referred to by the Composer, but that UI does not have an add function.

See: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/technical-marketing/posts/experience-commerce-entity-composer for an example of how they are used.

[image: Composer option to link to it][image: Empty item definition list]

In the Composer, they are referenced here, but the associate UI does not allow creating new ones.

Answer (score 2):

They are added directly to the catalog, in the details section: 
[image]